# Python string text to set of points

Tags: python, text

What is the easiest way to obtain a 'key' point set from some string text in Python? Please see the example. Key points are highlighted with blue and yellow. 
I need to build 3D figure based on this set later.

[image]

Comment: obtain 'key' point set from an image or from a string?

Comment: need to obtain from a string.

Comment: That would depend on the font, right? You also need to clarify your idea, what's the definition of a key point? Would the letter O have key points? For now, this question is too broad/unclear.

Comment: @sevatster you mean text -> to image -> get keypoint coordinates in image?

Comment: I need to build 3D figure based on this set later.
Updated the description

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO, but you may find the [FreeType](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py/) package helpful. You can use it to access the glyph geometry of a font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for a 3D Model you perhaps need more than only some few points think about the letter "S". Created some code to get generic the coordinates. You can play around with the size of the font, and picture size, to get more or less points. The arial.ttf was downloaded from https://github.com/JotJunior/PHP-Boleto-ZF2/blob/master/public/assets/fonts/arial.ttf

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont
import numpy as np
import cv2


print np.__version__

def getPixelColor(pixel, x, y):
    try:
        return pixel[x,y]
    except IndexError:
        return (255,255,255)

def hasNeighbourColor(color, pixels, x, y):
    if getPixelColor(pixels,x-1,y-1) == color or getPixelColor(pixels,x,y-1) == color or getPixelColor(pixels,x+1,y-1) == color \
        or getPixelColor(pixels,x-1,y) == color or getPixelColor(pixels,x+1,y) == color\
        or getPixelColor(pixels,x-1,y+1) == color or getPixelColor(pixels,x,y+1) == color or getPixelColor(pixels,x+1,y+1) == color:
        return True
    return False

def createMapOfLetter(letter):
    print "LETTER %s:" % letter
    print "---------"

    img = Image.new('RGB', (230, 230), "white")
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 300)
    d.text((15, -50), letter, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)
    img.save('letter-%s.png' % letter, 'png')

    pixels = img.load()

    ans = []

    for x in range(230):
        for y in range(230):
            if pixels[x,y] == (0,0,0):
                if hasNeighbourColor((255,255,255), pixels, x, y) and not hasNeighbourColor((255,0,0), pixels, x, y):
                    pixels[x,y] = (255,0,0)
                    ans.append([x,y])

    for x in range(230):
        for y in range(230):
            if pixels[x,y] != (255,0,0):
                pixels[x,y] = (255,255,255)

    img.save('letter_map-%s.png' % letter, 'png')
    print ans


createMapOfLetter('A')
```

The script creates the letter-[letter].png which looks like this. Left A right S

[image: lettera]
[image: letters]

And then creates a list of coordinates. The coordinates in a picture look like this. The script automatically creates a letter_map-[letter].png. Left A, Right S

[image: lettermap]
[image: lettermap-s]

The output of the coordinates for A look like this it.

```
[[15, 221], [17, 215], [17, 221], [19, 221], [21, 221], [22, 202], [23, 221], [25, 194], [25, 221], [27, 221], 
[29, 221], [30, 181], [31, 221], [33, 173], [33, 221], [35, 221], [37, 221], [38, 160], [39, 221], [41, 152], 
[41, 221], [43, 221], [45, 218], [46, 139], [49, 131], [52, 198], [53, 195], [54, 118], [54, 192], [57, 110], 
[61, 172], [62, 97], [62, 169], [63, 166], [65, 89], [67, 156], [69, 156], [70, 76], [71, 156], [73, 68], 
[73, 156], [75, 156], [76, 134], [77, 129], [77, 156], [78, 55], [78, 134], [79, 156], [80, 134], [81, 47], 
[81, 118], [81, 156], [82, 134], [83, 156], [84, 134], [85, 107], [85, 156], [86, 34], [86, 134], [87, 156], 
[88, 134], [89, 26], [89, 96], [89, 156], [90, 134], [91, 156], [92, 134], [93, 85], [93, 156], [94, 13], [94, 134], 
[95, 156], [96, 134], [97, 7], [97, 74], [97, 156], [98, 71], [98, 134], [99, 7], [99, 156], [100, 134], [101, 7], 
[101, 156], [102, 134], [103, 7], [103, 56], [103, 156], [104, 134], [105, 7], [105, 156], [106, 46], [106, 134], 
[107, 7], [107, 156], [108, 134], [109, 7], [109, 35], [109, 156], [110, 31], [110, 134], [111, 7], [111, 156], 
[112, 134], [113, 7], [113, 156], [114, 37], [114, 134], [115, 7], [115, 40], [115, 156], [116, 43], [116, 134], 
[117, 7], [117, 46], [117, 156], [118, 49], [118, 134], [119, 7], [119, 156], [120, 134], [121, 7], [121, 156], 
[122, 134], [123, 7], [123, 63], [123, 156], [124, 66], [124, 134], [125, 7], [125, 156], [126, 134], [127, 74], 
[127, 156], [128, 134], [129, 156], [130, 134], [131, 85], [131, 156], [132, 134], [133, 156], [134, 134], [135, 96], 
[135, 156], [136, 134], [137, 32], [137, 156], [138, 104], [138, 134], [139, 37], [139, 156], [140, 134], [141, 42], 
[141, 156], [142, 115], [142, 134], [143, 47], [143, 156], [144, 134], [145, 52], [145, 123], [145, 156], [146, 134], 
[147, 57], [147, 156], [148, 134], [149, 62], [149, 156], [151, 67], [151, 156], [153, 72], [153, 156], [155, 77], 
[155, 156], [157, 82], [157, 156], [159, 87], [160, 161], [164, 172], [168, 183], [171, 191], [175, 202], [178, 210], 
[180, 139], [182, 144], [182, 221], [184, 149], [184, 221], [186, 154], [186, 221], [188, 159], [188, 221], [190, 164], 
[190, 221], [192, 169], [192, 221], [194, 174], [194, 221], [196, 179], [196, 221], [198, 184], [198, 221], [200, 189], 
[200, 221], [202, 194], [202, 221], [204, 199], [204, 221], [206, 221], [208, 221], [210, 221], [212, 221]]
```

The output for the coordinates of S look like this

```
 [[30, 162], [31, 167], [35, 179], [38, 52], [39, 187], [41, 81], [43, 193], [47, 198], 
[49, 28], [52, 203], [57, 101], [57, 161], [58, 19], [61, 172], [62, 174], [64, 15], 
[66, 52], [66, 68], [67, 49], [67, 181], [68, 73], [68, 108], [69, 45], [70, 76], [70, 109], 
[71, 42], [71, 185], [74, 10], [75, 81], [77, 36], [78, 190], [78, 218], [80, 34], [85, 220], [86, 31], 
[89, 30], [89, 116], [89, 221], [90, 88], [91, 5], [91, 196], [93, 89], [97, 4], [98, 28], [103, 120], 
[107, 93], [107, 121], [111, 94], [111, 122], [127, 28], [128, 4], [130, 127], [134, 223], [135, 100], 
[136, 30], [139, 6], [139, 31], [140, 130], [140, 222], [143, 131], [146, 8], [148, 133], [154, 136], 
[156, 44], [157, 189], [157, 217], [159, 49], [161, 141], [162, 15], [162, 109], [163, 61], [163, 143], 
[164, 110], [166, 111], [167, 149], [167, 212], [168, 19], [169, 171], [177, 118], [177, 205], [182, 200], 
[188, 129], [189, 49], [190, 132], [190, 189], [195, 178], [197, 150]]
```

Comment: @sevatster You're welcome. if you need a higher resolution of the points, just say it, just convert the picture before reading the points into a black and white image.