# Python letter to Points in 2D-coordinates

Tags: python

I have a letter (for instance "A") and would want a defined number of points with 2d-coordinates that "paint" that letter.

So for instance Letter A, 20 points should return 20 points that when plotted spell out "A"

Similar to [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792935/python-string-text-to-set-of-points), but not the outline.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Thanks
Daniel

By now I can only assign the pixels by hand using a coordinate picker tool.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions on where to start?

I suggest trying [`pyfiglet`](https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/) which allows you to turn text into ASCII art, as it is external you need to first install it, then you might do for example

```
import pyfiglet
result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("A", font="3x5")
print(result)
```

gives output

```
 #  
# # 
### 
# # 
# #
```

Observe that result is instance of `pyfiglet.FigletString`, which is subclass of `str`, therefore you might treat it as `str` and detect positions of `#` following way

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(result.splitlines()):
    for columnno, character in enumerate(line):
        if character == "#":
            print(lineno, columnno)
```

which result in following output

```
1 1
2 0
2 2
3 0
3 1
3 2
4 0
4 2
5 0
5 2
```

Observe that this does output first number of line (y) followed by column number (x), you might elect to use reversed majority or starting counting at 1 rather than 0, in which case you should adjust shown code.